# Realm Flowable query filtering by the current date

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

**Context**

I'm working on an offline first app, and I'm basically working on a screen that is supposed to show a list of store offers - discounts, coupons, things like that - I'm trying to rely on Realm queries via Flowables to fetch the data, and I want the app to be 100% honest with what we have on the Realm DB. I mean, that if something changes in the database the app should immediately refresh the UI, that's why I'm using Flowables.

**Problem**

This approach has been working fine so far, but I've stumbled across this specific situation where things are a bit tricky. I need to display this list of store offers like this:

```
private val offersFlowable: Flowable<RealmResults<RealmOffer>>
        get() {
            val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
            return realm.where(RealmOffer::class.java)
                .equalTo("userId", CredentialManager.getInstance().getUserId())
                .and()
                .beginGroup()
                    .isNotNull("expiryDate").and().greaterThan("expiryDate", Date())
                .endGroup()
                .findAll()
                .asFlowable()
        }
```

The query itself works perfectly, I fetch the user's offers which haven't expired yet. The only problem is that *it seems I need to recreate this query every time I want to refresh the data*. Why? Because of the `Date()`. I open the `Activity` that renders this `RecyclerView` list of store offers, I instantiate the query and start listening for the changes - so far so good - but if I have a store offer that is about to expire in a minute or so, wait that full minute and do a Pull To Refresh, the expire offer doesn't go away. Again, because of the `Date()` because the current date was instantiated a minute ago and it is *still* that date.

If I kill the app or instantiate the `Activity` from scratch, everything works as expected because I'm instantiating the query again, therefore getting an up to date `Date()`.

**What I've tried so far**

- Instead of hardcoding that `Date()` arg there, having a `currentDate` property in my `ViewModel` - the place where this Flowable lives - I was kinda hoping that if the date arg was a reference to a *computed* Kotlin property that would do the trick, but it didn't work.
- Same thing as above but I changed the `expiryDate` field to millis instead of a `Date`.

**The Workaround**

So, the only thing that works right now is just re-instantiating the Flowable query every time I do a PTR, that way I pass an up to date `Date()` arg and the query works as expected.

**My Question**

Is there any way to fix this without having to re-instantiate the query all the time?

Thanks! Appreciate all feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I have understood your problem right, I would like to put a suggestion may be that help you. The current work around for sure is not a good option because of requesting the database again and again. so what in my opinion would be better for this situation is,

Before rendering the data on the RecyclerView, Do the following;

> 1 - get the expiry date & time of each item.
>
> 2 - get current date & time.
>
> 3 - Compare both of them and get the difference.

Now, if the difference is -ve value, it means the item is expired and you don't have to show it in recyclerView. Of course the item is available in ArrayList/List but it is not being rendered on recyclerView.

---

**Otherwise Second Option**

---

At the time of adding the store offers data to the database, just register a `PendingIntent` for every offer along with an `AlarmManager` and set the `Expriy-time` as the alarm time for the `PendingIntent`.

This way, when the offer expires, it will throw an alarm. So, here you could do the magic, when the `PendingIntent` get trigger, just update your database and recyclerview from there. This way you can handle every offer automatically.

Let me know if it helps.

Happy coding :)